# How can I filter my Gmail messages that aren't labeled?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I'd like to sort all of my Gmail messages that don't have label, so I can process them (I miss some every now and then).  I can sort by every label by clicking on it at the left, but how do you sort the unlabeled ones?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

**Updated:**
There is a [blog today](http://gmailblog.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/search-for-emails-by-size-and-more-in.html) about updated Gmail search modifiers that allow you to do this with a simple search!

```
has:nouserlabels
```

Note: Because of Gmails threading you will have labels on some of the messages in the derived list because some messages in a thread will have labeling while some won't. (From [Gmail Help - Advanced Search site](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en).)

**Original answer:**

The Gmail [advanced search](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=7190) help page says:

> `label:` Search for messages by label*
>
> **There isn't a search operator for unlabeled messages**
>
> Example: `from:amy label:friends`
>   Meaning: Messages from Amy that have the label "friends"
>
> Example: `from:david label:my-family`
>   Meaning: Messages from David that have the label "My Family"

Comment: Answer updated to reflect new Gmail search modifiers

Comment: `has:nouserlabels -label:Inbox -label:sent -label:Chats -label:drafts -label:trash` did the trick for me. You want also to filter the system labels out.

Comment: Thanks @volker! I label *some* messages in my Inbox, and needed to filter only on them, so I was able to use the converse too: label:inbox -has:nouserlabels to find them!

Comment: but has:nouserlabels will return any conversation that you replied to, since the labels are not copied to the sent sent message.

Comment: `has:nouserlabels` is broken for me since February 2, 2015. If I search for anything earlier, it won't find it no matter what.

Comment: @Mehrdad It still seems to work for me - I can go back to the first email from the Gmail team when I opened my account in 2004. Are you sure you haven't added some kind of 'archive' tag to emails before that date?

Comment: @MikeHouston: I think it's specific to my account somehow. Yeah I'm sure, there is no tag on those emails. It's just broken. I even tried adding and removing all of my tags to an email to no avail.

Comment: has: nouserlabels doesn't do anything for me (empty search). Ditto for has: userlabels. I'm guessing this feature is deprecated?

Answer (score 18):

One way you can do it is by using the minus operator on the label operator. So for example:

```
-label:tag-a -label:tag-b -label:tag-c
```

or for one-word tags:

```
-label:{taga tagb tagc}
```

This is probably only practical if you don't have a lot of labels.

Additionally, if they don't change often, you can include a link to this search so that it easily accessible from Gmail. There is a Google Labs product which puts a box of links on the left side and allows you to customize them. Just add a link to this search query and you'll be able to access your untagged messages easily.

[It seems like](http://theclosetentrepreneur.com/how-to-find-all-unlabeled-email-in-gmail) there is a greasemonkey script which will work too. Here is [the script's website](http://jaidev.info/home/hacks/gmailUnlabelled). It creates a special label, `Unlabelled`, to search for all the conversations without a real label.

Answer (score 12):

In my case I had lots of rubbish in the **All Mail** folder, mail that should have been deleted but accumulated there for some reason. I wanted to get rid of it without touching anything that was labelled **including** the nonuser labels. This did the trick:

```
has:nouserlabels -in:Inbox -in:Draft -in:Sent
```

Comment: "All Mail" is more than a label. It is literally _all_ your mail.

Comment: I'd also add `-is:chat`

Answer (score 9):

Google has the operator `has:nouserlabels` now. It works like a charm for what you want to do.

I don't know why it was so difficult to find for so long. Maybe it is fairly new.

Comment: It is new. It was part of [an update in the last week](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/search-for-emails-by-size-and-more-in.html). (Also mentioned in an update to the accepted answer.)

Comment: Well, it doesn't work like a charm, bringing up a bunch of posts that have labels also, but I'm excited that they are finally implementing something.

Answer (score 4):

I would try:

```
has:nouserlabels -in:trash -is:chat -in:inbox
```

Comment: `has:nouserlabels -in:inbox` worked for me, but, I like more Outlook/hotmail approach - in folders. I don't know why Gmail is so convoluted in this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

This works very well, except in my experience, it only shows 20 per page, no matter what your settings are, and won't show the total number to fix, but still... got the job done!
Put this in your inbox search box:

in:inbox has:nouserlabels

Comment: The question was to show all messages. Your answer just limits it to the inbox.