# Find messages which have no label

Tags: gmail-labels

My problem is about missing the messages from the labeling. I have a organized labels in my Gmail account but some old messages have no label. **I want to find and add them proper labels.**

Comment: Closely related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28081/how-to-show-messages-whose-only-label-is-inbox

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want find messages that don't have any of the labels you've created, it's as simple as a search for:

```
has:nouserlabels
```

If you want to find all messages that don't have any label at all, not even the system labels, try searching for

```
has:nouserlabels -in:inbox -in:spam -in:trash
```

This last will give you any message that doesn't have any of your labels and is not in your inbox, spam folder, or deleted messages.