# Missing important emails in Gmail that don't have labels

Tags: gmail-labels

I don't see emails in my inbox of Gmail because they don't have labels.  How can I get those to automatically show in my inbox?

Comment: Don't archive them.

Comment: are you using priority inbox?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a filter that archives (Skip Inbox) messages as they come in, all messages get the "Inbox" system label.

So, the first step would be to examine your filters to ensure they're not acting on messages you don't want them to.

Next, you can find messages that don't have any labels with the right search operators. (This is touched on in [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/275/how-can-i-filter-my-gmail-messages-that-arent-labeled).)

Search for:

```
has:nouserlabels
```

This specifically finds messages where there is not a user-created label.

You may want to specifically exclude some special folders, so you might add to your search:

```
has:nouserlabels -in:spam -in:trash -in:sent
```

The minus sign (`-`) indicates "NOT", so this search says "show me all messages with no user-created labels that are not in the spam, trash, or sent labels".

If this isn't what you're asking about, please clarify your question.

Comment: for example, emails forwarded to me from work usually arrive without a label and I don't have a filter set up for this

Comment: Then, unless you archive them, they'll have the "Inbox" label.